# Get list of filtered unique values from different sheet using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have below data

```
 Person Product id Purchased
X   43
Y   58
X   34
X   28
X   34
Y   26
Y   57
```

I need unique Product ids purchased by Person X using formula in excel in different sheet.

it seems very simple if I  use pivot table but just wanted to know if there is any way to get the desired values using formula.

Expected results are:

```
 Person Product id Purchased
X   43
X   34
X   28
```

Comment: With Office 365 you could use [`UNIQUE()`](https://exceljet.net/formula/unique-values-with-criteria) function

Comment: Thanks JvdV, but i am using office Professional plus 2016 and there is no function called Unique().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for example you could try:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$8,MATCH(0,IF($E$2=$A$2:$A$8,COUNTIF($F$1:$F1,$B$2:$B$8),""),0)),"")
```

Formula in `J2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$8,MATCH(0,IF($I$2=$A$2:$A$8,COUNTIF($J$1:$J1,$B$2:$B$8),""),0)),"")
```

Both entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

***Sidenote***:
Might you be interested, google spreadsheet can do the exact same thing as [`UNIQUE`](https://exceljet.net/formula/unique-values-with-criteria) does. For Example, with your sample data just type: `=UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B8,A2:A8="X"))` and it will create the whole list for you!

Comment: Thanks JvdV. Small request, Is it possible to get the same results using one formula?

Comment: You mean, to remove duplicate values? There is a built-in solution for that.